# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE

Tags: php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content">

<?php if (have_posts()): ?>

    <?php $i=0;?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php $i++;?>
    <div class="cols"<? if($i%3==0) echo ' style="margin-right:0"';?>>
        <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <?php $thumb=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image', true); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <?php if($thumb!=''){
            $thumb = str_replace(get_bloginfo('url').'/','',$thumb);
            ?>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/thumb.php?src=<?=$thumb;?>&w=183&h=140&zc=1" class="thumb" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
            <? } else { ?>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/pic.jpg" alt="" class="thumb" />
            <? } ?>
            </a>

            <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo cut_string(get_the_title(),30,'...'); ?></a></h2>
            <p><?php echo cut_string(get_the_content(),60,'...'); ?></p>
            <p class="meta">
            <?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { ?>
            <span class="views"><?php the_views(); ?></span> <?php } ?>
            <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comments'); ?>
            </p>
            <p><?php if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } ?> </p>

        </div></div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="page_navi"><?php page_navi();?></div>

<?php else: ?>

    <div class="post">
        <h2 class="title">Not Found</h2>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<!-- end content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Parse error:

> syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE in /home/fakecsc1/domains/jocuri2k.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/Games/index.php on line 36

What's the problem with this code? How can I fix it?

Comment: Questions should be more to focused on how to implement things and how to fix bugs in code which runs, but has the wrong behaviour. People are down voting you because you're question is answered by the error message you're getting.

Comment: I understand. How i said, this is my first question and i don't know the rules (still) .

Comment: You could say something which implies that you've at least read the error message:  "I've checked that all the brackets are balanced, but it still can't see the endwhile at the right point.  What could cause this?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like the problem is your use of [shorttags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) here: `<?` instead of `<?php`

```
 <? } else { ?>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/pic.jpg" alt="" class="thumb" />
            <? } ?>
            </a>
```

If your server isn't interpreting these as PHP, php will see the `endwhile` before it sees the close tags. Change them to `<?php` instead of `<?`.

Comment: I face the same issue on one of my old themes , it was single line I use `<?` instead of `<?php`